# ImportPythonUDFS throws a run-time error '53' (xlwings 0.6.1)

Tags: xlwings

I have Anaconda2(32-bit) installed on my computer(Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit), and I am using Microsoft Excel 2010(32-bit). I used ExcelPython previously, and it worked fine. Then I updated everything to xlwings 0.6.1 and deleted ExcelPython because xlwings and ExcelPython merged.

I added necessary xlwings.bas file to VBA as a module. When I press Alt+F8 button, which brings up "Macro" pop-up window, "ImportPythonUDFs" macro appears in the list. However, when I press "Run" button, it throws me "Run-time error '53'" error saying "File not found: xlwings32.dll".

Can anyone help me to figure out how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xlwings runs against the default Python installation (the one that you can invoke by just typing `python` at a command prompt) if you do not provide a path to your python.exe under the `Function Settings > PYTHON_WIN`, see the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/vba.html#settings).
So either your default Python installation isn't the one where you have xlwings installed, or there's something wrong with your xlwings installation: Make sure you have the xlwings32.dll sitting next to your python.exe. If that is not the case, uninstall and reinstall xlwings using pip or conda.
If its going against the wrong Python installation, you can either fix your PATH or point to the specific Python interpreter via VBA settings.

**Update**: This was a bug that happend on certain system configurations and has been fixed with v0.6.2

Comment: So, this is what I tried:

1) When I provided path to python.exe file in "PYTHON_WIN" field and executed "ImportPythonUDFs", this error message appeared: 
"Run-time error '1': Could not load xlwings32.dll from either of the following folders: C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2, C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Continuum"

2) I checked that my xlwings32.dll sits next to python.exe file.

Comment: 3) I tried uninstalling xlwings from computer by "pip uninstall xlwings". Command Prompt says that xlwings was successfully uninstalled. However, when I want to reinstall xlwings by typing "pip install  xlwings", Commad Prompt says "Requirement already satisfied". How is this possible if I just uninstalled xlwings entirely from my computer?

Comment: Do you mind opening an issue on GitHub? these discussions tend to become a bit lenghty for SO. It might be necessary to run a `conda remove xlwings` or it might have left over some folders that - if necessary - might be removed manually. In the end it's also a good idea to have Excel completely closed when installing/removing xlwings.

Comment: I opened this issue on GitHub. Using 'conda' instead of 'pip' also didn't help.